# Is ruby Array.sample safe for generating passwords?

Tags: ruby, passwords

How secure are passwords generated with the following algorithm?

```
a_z = ('a'..'z').to_a
Array.new(10).map{|_| a_z.sample}.join
```

Comment: Safe against which attacks?

Comment: Why do you need a dummy password?

Comment: If you have a good reason for generating these passwords, I would use `SecureRandom`.

Comment: I create the users from a csv table, and send emails to them asking them to change the password. I solved the problem using `Devise::friendly_token`. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such passwords are not technically cryptographically secure, because the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) algorithm used as the random number generator in `Array#sample` can in theory be hacked. Each letter that is sampled gives clues to the internal state of the number generator, and knowing enough of them (probably around 80 passwords generated sequentially in your scheme) is enough to start predicting the contents of future passwords.

In practice this would be very hard for a hacker to take advantage of, because they would need access to quite a few passwords all generated in the same process and know the sequence, before they could start reliably predicting passwords.

However, you could avoid this potential problem by using a cryptographic random number generator. Ruby has one as standard `SecureRandom`. SecureRandom cannot be connected to `Array#sample`, equivalent code to yours might be:

```
Array.new(10) { (97 + SecureRandom.random_number(26)).chr }.join
```

It doesn't look as elegant, but it is more difficult to hack.

Increasing the length of password, and the choice of available characters would also make the passwords harder to brute-force guess (by trying all possible combinations), but that is not a problem inherent to the approach of using `Array#sample` - you could just increase the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only able to generate `26^8` different passwords. I would consider this not not be very secure.

I would suggest using Ruby's [`SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) if you have to generate random passwords (btw `Devise::friendly_token` uses that library). And I would suggest to use longer passwords.

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
#=> "GL3tna7eQFpu1JaPnxIoyA"
```

That example can generate `64^22` different strings.